# Simple Matlab plot won't display point MarkerType

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using Matlab R2015b - academic use and the MarkerType '.' is not working in plot (it won't display, but the data has been plotted as I can click on it. Here is an example simple code that shows '*' and '-' working but not '.' I have tried restarting the computer and Matlab, but haven't tried reinstalling and would like to try avoiding that.

```
figure;
plot(10:-1:1,1:10,'r-'); hold on;
plot(1:20,1:20,'r.','MarkerSize',10); hold on;
plot(1:10,1:10,'r*','MarkerSize',10);
```

[image: "Dot Plot" not working]

In case this might help, when I type:

```
get(gcf)
             Alphamap: [1x64 double]
         BeingDeleted: 'off'
           BusyAction: 'queue'
        ButtonDownFcn: ''
             Children: [1x1 Axes]
             Clipping: 'on'
      CloseRequestFcn: 'closereq'
                Color: [0.9400 0.9400 0.9400]
             Colormap: [64x3 double]
            CreateFcn: ''
          CurrentAxes: [1x1 Axes]
     CurrentCharacter: ''
        CurrentObject: [1x1 Line]
         CurrentPoint: [355 267]
            DeleteFcn: ''
         DockControls: 'on'
             FileName: ''
    GraphicsSmoothing: 'on'
     HandleVisibility: 'on'
        IntegerHandle: 'on'
        Interruptible: 'on'
       InvertHardcopy: 'on'
          KeyPressFcn: {3x1 cell}
        KeyReleaseFcn: ''
              MenuBar: 'figure'
                 Name: ''
             NextPlot: 'add'
               Number: 1
          NumberTitle: 'on'
     PaperOrientation: 'portrait'
        PaperPosition: [0.2500 2.5000 8 6]
    PaperPositionMode: 'manual'
            PaperSize: [8.5000 11]
            PaperType: 'usletter'
           PaperUnits: 'inches'
               Parent: [1x1 Root]
              Pointer: 'arrow'
    PointerShapeCData: [16x16 double]
  PointerShapeHotSpot: [8 8]
             Position: [2932 266 560 420]
             Renderer: 'opengl'
         RendererMode: 'auto'
               Resize: 'on'
        SelectionType: 'normal'
       SizeChangedFcn: ''
                  Tag: ''
              ToolBar: 'auto'
                 Type: 'figure'
        UIContextMenu: [0x0 GraphicsPlaceholder]
                Units: 'pixels'
             UserData: []
              Visible: 'on'
  WindowButtonDownFcn: {3x1 cell}
WindowButtonMotionFcn: ''
    WindowButtonUpFcn: {3x1 cell}
    WindowKeyPressFcn: {3x1 cell}
  WindowKeyReleaseFcn: {3x1 cell}
 WindowScrollWheelFcn: ''
          WindowStyle: 'normal'
```

And when I type:

```
get(gca)
                   ALim: [0 1]
               ALimMode: 'auto'
 ActivePositionProperty: 'outerposition'
      AmbientLightColor: [1 1 1]
           BeingDeleted: 'off'
                    Box: 'on'
               BoxStyle: 'back'
             BusyAction: 'queue'
          ButtonDownFcn: ''
                   CLim: [0 1]
               CLimMode: 'auto'
         CameraPosition: [10 10 17.3205]
     CameraPositionMode: 'auto'
           CameraTarget: [10 10 0]
       CameraTargetMode: 'auto'
         CameraUpVector: [0 1 0]
     CameraUpVectorMode: 'auto'
        CameraViewAngle: 6.6086
    CameraViewAngleMode: 'auto'
               Children: [3x1 Line]
               Clipping: 'on'
          ClippingStyle: '3dbox'
                  Color: [1 1 1]
             ColorOrder: [7x3 double]
        ColorOrderIndex: 1
              CreateFcn: ''
           CurrentPoint: [2x3 double]
        DataAspectRatio: [10 10 1]
    DataAspectRatioMode: 'auto'
              DeleteFcn: ''
              FontAngle: 'normal'
               FontName: 'Helvetica'
               FontSize: 10
          FontSmoothing: 'on'
              FontUnits: 'points'
             FontWeight: 'normal'
              GridAlpha: 0.1500
          GridAlphaMode: 'auto'
              GridColor: [0.1500 0.1500 0.1500]
          GridColorMode: 'auto'
          GridLineStyle: '-'
       HandleVisibility: 'on'
                HitTest: 'on'
          Interruptible: 'on'
LabelFontSizeMultiplier: 1.1000
                  Layer: 'bottom'
         LineStyleOrder: '-'
    LineStyleOrderIndex: 1
              LineWidth: 0.5000
         MinorGridAlpha: 0.2500
     MinorGridAlphaMode: 'auto'
         MinorGridColor: [0.1000 0.1000 0.1000]
     MinorGridColorMode: 'auto'
     MinorGridLineStyle: ':'
               NextPlot: 'add'
          OuterPosition: [0 0 1 1]
                 Parent: [1x1 Figure]
          PickableParts: 'visible'
     PlotBoxAspectRatio: [1 0.7903 0.7903]
 PlotBoxAspectRatioMode: 'auto'
               Position: [0.1300 0.1100 0.7750 0.8150]
             Projection: 'orthographic'
               Selected: 'off'
     SelectionHighlight: 'on'
             SortMethod: 'childorder'
                    Tag: ''
                TickDir: 'in'
            TickDirMode: 'auto'
   TickLabelInterpreter: 'tex'
             TickLength: [0.0100 0.0250]
             TightInset: [0.0363 0.0532 0.0134 0.0202]
                  Title: [1x1 Text]
TitleFontSizeMultiplier: 1.1000
        TitleFontWeight: 'bold'
                   Type: 'axes'
          UIContextMenu: [0x0 GraphicsPlaceholder]
                  Units: 'normalized'
               UserData: []
                   View: [0 90]
                Visible: 'on'
                  XAxis: [1x1 NumericRuler]
          XAxisLocation: 'bottom'
                 XColor: [0.1500 0.1500 0.1500]
             XColorMode: 'auto'
                   XDir: 'normal'
                  XGrid: 'off'
                 XLabel: [1x1 Text]
                   XLim: [0 20]
               XLimMode: 'auto'
             XMinorGrid: 'off'
             XMinorTick: 'off'
                 XScale: 'linear'
                  XTick: [0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20]
             XTickLabel: {11x1 cell}
         XTickLabelMode: 'auto'
     XTickLabelRotation: 0
              XTickMode: 'auto'
                  YAxis: [1x1 NumericRuler]
          YAxisLocation: 'left'
                 YColor: [0.1500 0.1500 0.1500]
             YColorMode: 'auto'
                   YDir: 'normal'
                  YGrid: 'off'
                 YLabel: [1x1 Text]
                   YLim: [0 20]
               YLimMode: 'auto'
             YMinorGrid: 'off'
             YMinorTick: 'off'
                 YScale: 'linear'
                  YTick: [0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20]
             YTickLabel: {11x1 cell}
         YTickLabelMode: 'auto'
     YTickLabelRotation: 0
              YTickMode: 'auto'
                  ZAxis: [1x1 NumericRuler]
                 ZColor: [0.1500 0.1500 0.1500]
             ZColorMode: 'auto'
                   ZDir: 'normal'
                  ZGrid: 'off'
                 ZLabel: [1x1 Text]
                   ZLim: [-1 1]
               ZLimMode: 'auto'
             ZMinorGrid: 'off'
             ZMinorTick: 'off'
                 ZScale: 'linear'
                  ZTick: [-1 0 1]
             ZTickLabel: ''
         ZTickLabelMode: 'auto'
     ZTickLabelRotation: 0
              ZTickMode: 'auto'
```

Comment: After playing around more, I have an update. For any '.' MarkerSize above 16, the dots display (appropriately large), but for any MarkerSize 15 and under, the dots are not visible.

Answer (score 1):

I you see unusual plotting in MATLAB one thing to try is to change out `OpenGL` rendering for `Painters` ([ref](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html)). You can do this by running:

```
set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'painters')
```

And see if the problem persists. The default is `OpenGL`.

If this solves the problem you might consider updating your video card driver and/or a fresh install of MATLAB. Also, if you haven't already, try a nice reboot.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it. You were right about the Painters command working and after updating my video card driver, the problem was solved.